# aws python CDK ECS cluster service subnet assignment. ec2.SubnetSelection

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc

I created a VPC

```py
vpc = ec2.Vpc(
    self,
    VPC_CONFIG["vpc_name"],
    cidr=VPC_CONFIG["cidr"],
    nat_gateways=VPC_CONFIG["nat_gateways"],
    subnet_configuration=[],
    enable_dns_support=True,
    enable_dns_hostnames=True,
)
```

Next, I created some beautiful subnets

```py
for subnet in SUBNETS:
    subnet_created = ec2.CfnSubnet(
        self,
        subnet["name"],
        vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id,
        cidr_block=subnet["cidr_block"],
        availability_zone=subnet["availability_zone"],
        tags=[{"key": "Name", "value": subnet["name"]}],
        map_public_ip_on_launch=True,
    )
```

Next, I created a cluster with a service. **I want to allocate my service in my private subnet**, so I tried

```py
cluster = ecs.Cluster(self, "MyCluster", vpc=vpc)

task_definition = ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(
    self,
    f"{VPC_CONFIG['vpc_name']}-MyFargateTaskDefinition",
    memory_limit_mib=512,  # 512 is 0.5 GB
    cpu=256,  # 256 is 0.25 vCPU
)

task_definition.add_container(
    f"{VPC_CONFIG['vpc_name']}-MyBackendContainer",
    image=ecs.ContainerImage.from_registry(BACKEND_CONFIG["docker_image"]),
    memory_reservation_mib=256,
)

print("-"*10, ">", private_subnet, ":(")
# ----------> <aws_cdk.aws_ec2.CfnSubnet object at 0x000001DB96834890> :(
service = ecs.FargateService(
    self,
    "MyService",
    cluster=cluster,
    task_definition=task_definition,
    desired_count=1,
    assign_public_ip=False,
    vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(subnets=[private_subnet]),
    security_groups=[private_sec_gp],
)
```

The trouble here is that I run `cdk synth`, and I checked my file and I found that `vpc_subnets` is empty

[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkTUK.png]

So, after some exhausing hours of researching I found out that `ec2.SubnetSelection(subnets=)` expects `Sequence[ISubnet]` type and I have `CfnSubnet`. I'm not sure if that's the problem. I ommited some code here, but I assume that it's not revelant for solving this :(

I'm stuck because when I run `cdk deploy` cloudFormation says this

`MyService/Service (MyServiceB4132EDA) Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: CreateService error: subnets can not be empty. (Service: AmazonECS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: 1643b0eb-61dc-45c8-800a-989ce8ab6c0f; Proxy: null)" (RequestToken: 2ebb2a5c-c39e-03b1-f5e2-6f6284360b97, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)`

Comment: Why are you using the L1 `CfnSubnet` construct instead of the L2 subnet? And you're right -- the type is wrong. `CfnSubnet` does not implement the [`ISubnet` interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.ISubnet.html), which is implemented by L2 subnet constructs only, such as [`ec2.PrivateSubnet`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.PrivateSubnet.html) or [`ec2.Subnet`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Subnet.html). Your code also doesn't show how the `private_subnet` variable is defined.

Comment: I see. Happens that I'm learning how to code with this library hahaha The information you gave made me dawn on lots of things. I think I will refactor all my code, replacing all the Cfn constructors. Yeah, I didn't show `private_subnet ` definition, It is just a instance of CfnSubnet, as you can see in the print statement. So, I will fix this with L2 constructors.

Comment: That will probably address your issue. In general, you don't want to use an L1 construct unless you absolutely have to. You might also consider configuring your subnets while creating the vpc object. You also _usually_ don't have to explicitly define the subnet your service uses, unless there's some specific networking constraint you have. Omitting `vpc_subnets` will cause it to choose any available private subnet (when `assign_public_ip` is `False` otherwise, public subnets will be used). You'll need subnets of the correct type to exist in the same VPC as the defined cluster.

Comment: Finally I understood how L2 construct works. It is kind of shady, but it makes sense jeje I saved lots of lines of code. Indeed, Cnf contruct forced me to explicitly create all the steps, but the magic of CDK is to do things as easy as possible. The trick was understanding `subnet_type` in `ec2.SubnetConfiguration`. Thank you my bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of configuring the subnets directly in the VPC construct:

```
subnet_config = [
    ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
        name="PublicSubnet",
        subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
        cidr_mask=21,
    ),
    ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
        name="PrivateSubnet",
        subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS,
        cidr_mask=19,
    ),
    ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
        name="IsolatedSubnet",
        subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
        cidr_mask=22,
    ),
    ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
        name="VpnSubnet",
        subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
        cidr_mask=27,
    ),
]

# Create the VPC using the L2 construct
self.vpc = ec2.Vpc(
    scope=self,
    id="Vpc",
    max_azs=2,
    nat_gateways=0,
    subnet_configuration=subnet_config,
    ip_addresses=ec2.IpAddresses.cidr(cidr_block="10.10.0.0/16"),
)
```

Then you access it like this:

```
ec2.SubnetSelection(subnet_group_name="PublicSubnet")
ec2.SubnetSelection(subnet_group_name="VpnSubnet")
...
```

Comment: Great, I had many doubts but finally I used your code. The trick was to understand how `subnet_type` works. Super useful and convenient